# Trying to use a div as a separator for different sections

Tags: html, css

Essentially I am trying to use the `<Div>` tag to create a bottom border to separate different content on the page but when I scroll to the bottom and insert the div there to separate them, it will ignore the other tags I have put and attached itself to the previous div separator.

How can I fix this? I tried using a HR tag but it did the same.

This is my code:

```css
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#leftcolumn,
#rightcolumn {
  border: none;
  float: left;
  min-height: 450px;
  color: white;
}
#leftcolumn {
  width: 50%;
}
.container {
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
}
#rightcolumn {
  /*    height: 100%;*/
  width: 40%;
  float: right;
  background-color: #c9ccc9;
}
.border {
  border-bottom: 40px solid #8dc43f;
}
p {
  color: black;
}
.infotext {
  color: #8dc43f;
  margin-left: 30%;
  font-family: 'ABeeZee', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.infotexttitle {
  color: #8dc43f;
  margin-left: 25%;
  font-family: 'ABeeZee', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.infotexttitlepower {
  color: #8dc43f;
  margin-left: 36%;
  font-family: 'ABeeZee', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.infotexttitlecomm {
  color: #8dc43f;
  margin-left: 17%;
  font-family: 'ABeeZee', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.bluetags {
  width: 264px;
  padding: 0;
  /*    transform:rotate(180deg);*/
  display: block;
  /*    border-collapse:collapse;*/
  margin-left: 176px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.greentags {
  width: 264px;
  padding: 0;
  /*    transform:rotate(180deg);*/
  display: block;
  /*    border-collapse:collapse;*/
  margin-left: 180px;
  margin-top: -26px;
}
.orangetags {
  width: 280px;
  padding: 0;
  /*    transform:rotate(180deg);*/
  display: block;
  /*    border-collapse:collapse;*/
  margin-left: 175px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  /* for IE 6 */
}
.titleimg {
  margin-left: -60%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
imagetext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.bgimg {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
#text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 43%;
  top: 25%;
  font-family: 'ABeeZee', sans-serif;
}
#secondtext {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 37%;
  top: 30%;
  font-family: 'ABeeZee', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
    <img src="turtletag.png" class="titleimg">
    <li><a href="#backtotop"><span>Home</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#features"><span>Features</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#app"><span>App</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#products"><span>Products</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Support</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<img src="googlestore.png" style="position:absolute; top:210px;left:70px; width: 10%;">
<img src="appstore.png" style="position:absolute; top:320px; left:77px; width:10%;">
<a href="#" class="myButton">Order Tags</a>
<img src="iPhone5_Mockup_Template_Free_by_Ray.png" class="bgimg">
<p id="text">Turtle Tags</p>
<p id="secondtext">Always connected to the nest</p>
<div class="border"></div>

<div id="leftcolumn">
  <div class="mainbody">
    <img src="bluetags.png" class="bluetags hvr-float">
  </div>
  <div class="mainbody">
    <img src="greentags.png" class="greentags hvr-float">
  </div>
  <div class="mainbody">
    <img src="orangetag.png" class="orangetags hvr-float">
  </div>
</div>
<a name="features"></a>
<div id="rightcolumn">
  <h2 class="infotext">Features</h2>
  <hr class="newstyle">
  <img src="battery.png" style="margin-left:40%; width:15%">
  <p class="infotexttitle">Long battery life</p>
  <p rows="4" columns="4" style="width:350px;margin-left:100px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur urna enim, aliquet non sagittis sit amet, euismod luctus risus. Aliquam venenatis arcu quam, id hendrerit dolor fermentum sed. Nullam congue molestie dolor quis egestas. Suspendisse
    potenti.
  </p>
  <img src="speaker-xxl.png" style="margin-left:45%; width:10%; margin-top:30px;">
  <p class="infotexttitle">Noise Notifications</p>
  <p rows="4" columns="4" style="width:350px;margin-left:100px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur urna enim, aliquet non sagittis sit amet, euismod luctus risus. Aliquam venenatis arcu quam, id hendrerit dolor fermentum sed. Nullam congue molestie dolor quis egestas. Suspendisse potenti.
  </p>
  <img src="powericon.png" style="margin-left:45%; width:10%; margin-top:30px;">
  <p class="infotexttitlepower">Always on</p>
  <p rows="4" columns="4" style="width:350px;margin-left:100px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur urna enim, aliquet non sagittis sit amet, euismod luctus risus. Aliquam venenatis arcu quam, id hendrerit dolor fermentum sed. Nullam congue molestie dolor quis egestas. Suspendisse potenti.
  </p>
  <img src="twoway.png" style="margin-left:45%; width:10%; margin-top:30px;">
  <p class="infotexttitlecomm">Two way communication</p>
  <p rows="4" columns="4" style="width:350px; margin-left:100px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur urna enim, aliquet non sagittis sit amet, euismod luctus risus. Aliquam venenatis arcu quam, id hendrerit dolor fermentum sed. Nullam congue molestie dolor quis egestas. Suspendisse potenti.
  </p>
</div>
```

I've tried changing the css and I can't find anything that would cause it, But a fresh pair of eyes may be able to find something I cannot.

Comment: Create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) which works so that its easier to work on it.

Comment: its difficult to diagnose the problem when you just paste your entire code. I copy/pasted this to jsfiddle, but I still don't know what you want. https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/ghogvcsx/3/

Comment: @AbdulAhmad The green border that you see at the top I am trying to get it at the bottom of the page as well as I can separate 2 sections of the page, but when using the div again it will add onto the green border at the top doubling it in size

Comment: This is a lot of code for replicating a problem with a div and formatting.  What's the minimum code you can use to demonstrate the problem?  That will help make diagnosis much more manageable.

Comment: looks fine and works as you expect https://jsfiddle.net/ks8srzc4/

Comment: @AniMenon Thanks! I have created a fiddle now https://jsfiddle.net/zakbeager/afaco9po/

Comment: @Reddy Where the grey box ends after the first border that is where I want the second border to be as there will be more beneath it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here comes from how you constructed your page. You have a left/right column that was built using `floats`. when you use float, it takes the content in the float out of the general flow of the page. Try to remove those floats and it should work as expected.

I removed your floats in the fiddle and the border started working right.

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/ghogvcsx/4/

here's a basic idea on how floats work: the top boxes don't overlap because there is no float, but the bottom 2 boxes you only see green because the red one is floated so the green one takes its space. to avoid this, add an explicit height to the floated div, but then you can't have dynamically expanding content. https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/bL8qLa6j/2/

and here's a basic idea of how columns work: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/bL8qLa6j/5/

Comment: Thanks! that works! but then would I just margin the div to the right to get it back how it was previously? but with the box at the bottom?

Comment: @zakbeager no you need to use `inline-block` to get 'columns' on a page. its a cleaner approach